# How do I find where java is downloaded on a windows 7 computer

Tags: java, windows-7

I am Wondering how to find where java has downloaded on my windows 7 computer. I need to find it so I can make a 'JAVA_HOME'.

Comment: Look in `Program Files\Java` or `Program Files (x86)\Java` for the default installation location

Comment: @user3478462-Kindly mark the answer as accepted if satisfied with my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Go to this location,if it exists,in your Windows 7 PC :-

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac.exe   // 64 bit system compatible JDK
                     OR
C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin\javac.exe   //32 bit system comaptible JDK
```

If this location shows you the **"javac.exe"** application, then JDK has been successfully installed in your system. And, you can set up your environment variable to point to the JDK location as

```
'JAVA_HOME'=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0  // as shown in my system!
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Control Panel"->"Java"
2. Select "Java" Tab
3. Click on "view"
4. You will see your installed Java version with path