# Trying to run Maven but JAVA_HOME not found

Tags: java, windows, maven

I'm trying to get Maven to work on my Windows 7 OS.

```
$ mvn -v
which: no javac in (/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Symantec/VIP Access Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91:/cygdrive/c/texlive/2016/bin/win32:/cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit)
which: no java in (/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Symantec/VIP Access Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91:/cygdrive/c/texlive/2016/bin/win32:/cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit)
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute
```

After searching online, I found that I need to add the path of my  Java installation to my system's PATH variable. However, I can't find the path to my Java installation:

```
$ whereis java
java:

$ which java
which: no java in (/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/OpenSSH/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Symantec/VIP Access Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91:/cygdrive/c/texlive/2016/bin/win32:/cygdrive/c/Users/anyoung/AppData/Local/Box/Box Edit)
```

I have verified that Java is installed (Version 8) by typing "Java" in my search bar. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you run `which java` and share the result?

Comment: Come on... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: add enviornmental variable JAVA_HOME to point to installation directory of java .

Comment: Closing as duplicate as one of the many questions with a highly similar title relating to setting JAVA_HOME on Windows. If you can differentiate your question from all of the other questions on the same topic already it can be reopened.

Comment: @djechlin This is NOT A DUPLICATE. The problem is NOT in setting JAVA_HOME, but in setting the PATH correctly.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174906/how-do-i-find-where-java-is-downloaded-on-a-windows-7-computer?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: @djechlin I can tell you exactly where the JRE is located in the OP's machine (it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91`) but the problem is that he's got a space before it in the PATH which causes Cygwin to fail to recognize it as /cygdrive/c, and therefore fails to find it. He also doesn't appear to have a JDK (required for mvn) but only a JRE. So, as you can see, different issues to those you say are duplicates.

Comment: You're mixing cygwin and native Windows paths in your PATH variable: `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91`

Comment: @djechlin This particular problem is likely cygwin-related rather than Java-related.